# Keyboard not working after update

Tags: updates, keyboard, dpkg

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 and after performing a software update to kernel version 6.2.0-32 as well as others (read below), I was prompted to reboot and after that the keyboard of my laptop (a Fujitsu Lifebook E5410) did not type anymore, whereas the trackpad is still working. I have plugged in an external keyboard that works.

When I go into the grub menu upon booting and enter the shell there, the laptop keyboard does work.

I have looked at various "ubuntu keyboard broke after update" entries on google that do not work (such as apt-installing xorg-related drivers or blacklisting modules such as inter_vbtn and elan).
I have also tried to boot with an earlier kernel (6.2.0-26) via grub-menu, same issue.

At this point I am at the end of my tether. While the external keyboard works, I need to carry my laptop around an I can not relinquish the use of the laptop-keyboard.

Any ideas what else I could try? Any pointers to packages that could be the culprit? - Thanks!

This is the packages that could have caused the issue (these are the relevant entries from `/var/log/dpkg.log`):

```
brave-browser
google-chrome-stable
libsmbclient
libwbclient0
samba-libs
microsoft-edge-stable
libjson-c5
docker.io
git-man
git
gnome-remote-desktop
initramfs-tools
initramfs-tools-core
initramfs-tools-bin
linux-firmware
linux-modules-6.2.0-32-generic
linux-image-6.2.0-32-generic
linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-32-generic
amd64-microcode
linux-generic-hwe-22.04
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04
linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-32
linux-headers-6.2.0-32-generic
linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04
linux-libc-dev
mokutil
openjdk-11-jre
openjdk-11-jre-headless
zotero
microsoft-edge-stable
google-chrome-stable
mokutil
linux-firmware
zotero
openjdk-11-jre-headless
linux-libc-dev
openjdk-11-jre
docker.io
amd64-microcode
linux-modules-6.2.0-32-generic
libwbclient0
linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-32
linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-32-generic
brave-browser
git-man
linux-headers-6.2.0-32-generic
linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04
libjson-c5
initramfs-tools-bin
linux-image-6.2.0-32-generic
samba-libs
git
libsmbclient
initramfs-tools-core
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04
linux-generic-hwe-22.04
initramfs-tools
gnome-menus
gnome-remote-desktop
libglib2.0-0
libc-bin
man-db
shared-mime-info
mailcap
desktop-file-utils
hicolor-icon-theme
linux-image-6.2.0-32-generic
initramfs-tools
linux-headers-5.19.0-50-generic
linux-headers-5.19.0-50-generic
linux-headers-5.19.0-50-generic
linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-50
linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-50
linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-50
linux-image-5.19.0-50-generic
linux-image-5.19.0-50-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-50-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-50-generic
linux-modules-5.19.0-50-generic
linux-modules-5.19.0-50-generic
cpp-12
libasan8
libtsan2
libgcc-12-dev
gcc-12
dctrl-tools
dkms
flex
bison
libelf-dev
libfl2
libfl-dev
libiberty-dev
libudev-dev
libpci-dev
libssl-dev
flex
cpp-12
libssl-dev
libelf-dev
libudev-dev
libfl2
libiberty-dev
libasan8
bison
libtsan2
dctrl-tools
libpci-dev
libfl-dev
libgcc-12-dev
gcc-12
dkms
libc-bin
man-db
install-info
```

Update: I suspect this to be an issue of kernel 6.x.x-x + Lifebook or whatever in general. My workaround for now has been to install 5.19.0-50 and downgrade (this requires disabling secure boot in BIOS) and hope for some patches in the future.

Comment: You could report the problem to the Ubuntu developers if the kernel is maintained by Ubuntu, but if it's a mainline kernel, report it to the developers at [kernel.org](https://kernel.org/)

Answer (score 0):

This reported bug is related to what you describe: [Ubuntu bug 2033271](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2033271)

Within that bug's comments, the following workaround was called out:

- At the terminal, enter `sudoedit /etc/default/grub`
- Enter your password
- In the editor (nano, by default) find the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, and edit it to add the text `i8042.nomux`. For example, it may look like this afterward:
  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nomux`
- Save and close the editor (in nano, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd> to save)
- Run the command `sudo update-grub` to update the Linux kernel parameters based on the file you just edited